# AltBeacon sometime cannot range beacons

Tags: android, altbeacon, beacon, estimote

I want my app track with beacon all the time

it seem work fine been a while when it start tracking

after that, `didRangeBeaconsInRegion()` has an empty beacons collection

Here my code

```
public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "create");

        beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);

        try {
            beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().clear();
            beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
            beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1101l);
            beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(1101l);
            beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(1101l);
            beaconManager.updateScanPeriods();
        } catch (RemoteException e) { }

        backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);
        startBeaconRanging();
    }

    public void startBeaconRanging() {
        courseId = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getString(getString(R.string.course_id), "");
        Log.d(TAG, "startBeaconRanging on courseId = " + courseId);

        if (!courseId.equals("")) {
            syncBeaconWithFirebase(courseId);
            endTime = CourseSQLiteManager.getColumnById(getApplicationContext(), courseId, COURSE_ENDTIME);
            regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, new Region("ranged region", null, null, null));
        }

    }

    public void stopBeaconRanging() {
        if (regionBootstrap != null) {
            regionBootstrap.disable();
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "end");
                courseId = "";
                beaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(getRegion());
                beaconManager.removeAllRangeNotifiers();
            } catch (RemoteException e) { }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
        Log.d(TAG, "enter");
        try {
            Region r = getRegion();
            if(r == null) {
                regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, new Region("ranged region", null, null, null));
                Log.d(TAG, "null");
            }
            if(r != null) {
                beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(r);
                beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(this);
            }
        } catch (RemoteException e) {    }
    }

    @Override
    public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
        try {
            if(getRegion() != null) beaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(getRegion());
        } catch (RemoteException e) {    }
    }

    @Override
    public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int i, Region region) {

    }

    @Override
    public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
        if(beacons.size() > 0) {
            Beacon beacon = beacons.iterator().next();
            Log.d(TAG, beacon.getId2().toInt() + " " + beacon.getDistance() + " " + beacon.getRssi());

            if(isAfterEndTime()) {
                stopBeaconRanging();
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT: It happen like this both foreground and background. But If I kill my app and open it again, I can finds beacon but just a moment too.

EDIT2: `isAfterEndTime` is return false while it cannot finds any beacons. But the `didExitRegion` is triggered swap with `didEnterRegion` and it finds zero beacons

PS. I want to track with only one beacon at a time

PS.2 Sorry for my bad English. I'm not sure, are you get what I want to ask clearly or not?

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check:

- Make sure this code is not being triggered.  I cannot see the definition of the method, but if it returns true, it will cause ranging to stop:

  ```
      if(isAfterEndTime()) {
          stopBeaconRanging();
      }
  ```
- Add a debug line in the `didExitRegion` to make sure it is not being called.  (Since it also stops ranging.)  As an aside, I don't think you need code that does this -- there is no efficiency cost to just continuing ranging if you aren't detecting beacons anyway.
- Make sure this line of code is only executed once, as the RegionBootstrap is not designed to be created repeatedly:

  ```
  regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, new Region("ranged region", null, null, null));
  ```

Rather than repeatedly making a new RegionBootstrap object, just create one once at the beginning of your program.  If you then want to change the monitored regions, you can do so with `beaconManager.stopMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region1);` and `beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region2);`

Comment: the `isAfterEndTime` is returns false. But For the `didExitRegion` it swap between this method and `didEnterRegion` , and at the time beacon collection is zero size. I don't understand why my app do like this.